# Shape of a boomerang

Tags: plotting, interpolation, code-request, integral-equations

I want to create a physical pendulum in 2D with the shape of a boomerang. And first problem I met with was how to define a boomerang, so I could have a shape of it and use it to make my pendulum. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: If you know the shape of your boomerang, define an `ImplicitRegion` . Now it's possible to calculate the  `RegionCentroid[]` and `MomentOfInertia[]`. That's sufficient to simulate the pendulum.

Answer (score 8):

I do not clearly understand your question. However, if you want to plot the shape of a boomerang use the following code.

```
ParametricPlot[{0.5 Cos[t] + 1.5*Cos[t]^2, 1.5*Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Based on @user84456's helpful answer we can evaluate the parameters needed for the simulation (see my comment )

```
breg = DiscretizeRegion[ParametricRegion [{0.5 Cos[t] + 1.5*Cos[t]^2,1.5*Sin[t] }, {{t, 0, 2 \[Pi]} } ]];

bum = BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[breg], MeshCells[breg, 1]];
```

[image]

simulation parameters

```
rc=RegionCentroid[reg] (*{1.12394, -0.0000217653}*)
JS=NIntegrate[# . # &[{x, y} - rc], Element[{x, y}, bum]] (*1.79862*)
```